# How strong is an countable infinity large circult?

Tags: computability

To give a clear definition:

1) No wire delay

2) Any number of bits(including infinity) doing NAND(and therefore all the lead-out logics) operation cost O(1) time

3) There are only finite layers(so you can't find a logic chain longer than a fixed value)

4) There may be an input of countable infinity size

To define calculate: You are allowed to say, for i in N(0 to infinity), or maybe a few for's, (a,f(i))->(c,g(i)), where a<c, and f and g are functions with plus, minus and merge(packing two integers into one). The expression should be finite.

E.g. Increase a binary number a[inf]..a[0] by 1:

f[i] = a[i] xor (a[i-1] and a[i-2] and ... and a[0])

E.g.2 Add two binary numbers a[inf..0] and b[inf..0]:

u[i] = a[i] or b[i]

t[i] = a[i] and b[i]

s[i][j] = u[i-1] and u[i-2] and ... and u[i-j]

c[i] = t[i-1] or (t[i-2] and s[i][1]) or (t[i-3] and s[i][2]) or ... or (t[0] and s[i][i-1])

f[i] = c[i] xor a[i] xor b[i]

E.g.3 Adding two real numbers: Get (0.a[0]a[1]a[2]...+0.b[0]b[1]b[2]...)mod 1

f[i] = a[i] xor b[i] xor ((a[i+1] and b[i+1]) or ((a[i+1] or b[i+1]) and (a[i+2] and b[i+2])) or ((a[i+1] or b[i+1]) and (a[i+2] or b[i+2]) and (a[i+3] and b[i+3]))...)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? By infinity as the input, do you mean INF - a number that tells it is not a number or do you really mean that infinite input costs one unit to read?

Comment: We have an infinity circult, which means that there can be infinity parallel calculating, so there should be nothing strange if it can handle an infinity size input. 2) makes it possible to get a result bit affected by an infinity number of inputs.

Comment: It's a curiousty problem. I'm not stuck at xx.

Comment: Everything can be computed using depth 2 circuits, so it seems your circuit will be able to compute any function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. A single circuit has a fixed number of inputs and, since there are only finitely many different functions $\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$ for any $n$, you only need finitely many gates to express anything that can be expressed.

Comment: And what would it mean to have infinitely many inputs to a single circuit? How would you specify the value of those inputs?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus You are right. here it's hard to tell "calculate" from "store". I modified to "only allow a countable infinity", because there are uncountable infinity functions that take a countable infinity bool args.

Comment: @David Richerby Specifying the inputs may be something that a[i]=[(pi*2^i)mod 2==1] or anything, which is not a problem

Comment: What is " a[i]=[(pi*2^i)mod 2==1]"? You haven't defined any of those symbols.

Comment: @David Richerby It means the i-th input is the i-th digit in the binary representation of pi